# Update the time provided using moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, dynamic, momentjs

i have a function where i get the utc time from the database like "`2015-10-28T18:02:44`" and i want to update the time using set interval in moment.js 
so that it gives me the output like `8:02:53 am` and after a second `8:02:54 am` just like a normal clock.
so far i have this code which doesn't seems to work

```
function update() {
    var date = moment(new Date("2015-10-28T18:02:44"));
    console.log(date.format('h:mm:ss a'));
};

setInterval(function(){
    update();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Are you getting Date from database within the update function? Or just get it once before and update afterwards?

Comment: Hello i am getting it before hitting the update function this is just for example

Comment: @aarjithn its not working even getting before the function

Comment: Yes, is it the current time that you need? Why would you need to get time from database instead just from javascript?

Comment: nopes i dont need current time, i will be getting the time from dababase

Comment: according to the time from database i need to update the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the date before the update function, and within it just add a second and then format it.

```
var date = moment.utc("2015-10-28T18:02:44").local();

function update() {
    console.log(date.add(1, "s").format('h:mm:ss a'));
};

setInterval(function(){
    update();
}, 1000);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pd88ka8y/7/)

*Make sure the setInterval is set to 1000 (1s)*

Comment: hi the time gets updated but the time is actually wrong "18:02:44" sould turn to "06:02:44" but its converting to "12:02:44"

Comment: Well I'm seeing it converted it into 06:02:44. What timezone do you live?

Comment: Can you try `date.add(1, "s").utc().format('h:mm:ss a')`

Comment: I updated your answer.  The string should be parsed by `moment` rather than the `Date` object, and it should be parsed *as UTC*, then switched back to local mode.

Comment: @MattJohnson Cool, thanks. Might have worked for me as I'm in living in UTC timezone.